# Is it possible to conditionally use AlpineJS event with Django templates?

Tags: django-templates, alpine.js

I have a select with an AlpinheJS `@change` event that changes the path based on the selected option:

```html
<select role="menu"
        id="LanguageSelector"
        @change="location.pathname = '/' + $event.target.value + '{{ request.path }}'.slice(3)">
</select>
```

I want to use this select in another page where I don't want the `@change` to work:

```html
{% include "shop/components/layout/header/language_selector.html" with enable_onchange=False %}
```

But I can't figure it out.

I've modified the select in any way I knew, but nothing works:

```html
<div x-data="{ shouldChange: `{{ enable_onchange|default:True }}` }">
{#{% with should_change=enable_onchange|default:True|yesno:"true,false" %}#}
{#  <div x-data="{ shouldChange: '{{ should_change }}' }">#}
{#{% endwith %}#}
<select role="menu"
        id="LanguageSelector"
          {% if enable_onchange|default:True %}@change="location.pathname = '/' + $event.target.value + '{{ request.path }}'.slice(3)"{% endif %}>
{#        @change="shouldChange ? location.pathname = '/' + $event.target.value + '{{ request.path }}'.slice(3) : void(0)">#}
</select>
</div>
```

I've commented out the alternative method I attempted.
`@change` fires no matter the code.

But if I modify `default` to `False` then `@change` won't work.
So it seems that I don't receive `enable_onchange` from `{% include "shop/components/layout/header/language_selector.html" with enable_onchange=False %}` ?

I don't want to use `<script>` tags.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Django, but I think you must remove quotes and backticks when you echo the *enable_onchange* in the html.
If you enclose the value in quotes, it will always be true because as a boolean value it will be equivalent to a non-empty string, therefore always true
Try something like:

```html
<div x-data="{ shouldChange: {{ enable_onchange|default_if_none:True|yesno:"true,false" }} }">
```

You can also check the result in your browser DOM inspector

Regarding the *"default"* filter, from the documentation I can see that it is used to convert *False* value to another value, so, in your way, when you pass False, the result will ever be True.
Instead of *"default"* filter try the *"default_if_none"* filter